# Lightweight ORM for SQLite

Tags: php, orm

I am looking for a lightweight PHP ORM for SQLite. I don't care which pattern it uses.

I just want it to be lightweight and easy to use.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good PHP ORM Library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library)

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But I have two main criteria: 1. Lightweight 2. I want to use it just with SQLite.

Comment: the first criteria that you have is subjective and as far as the second is concerned, there are frameworks in this post that support it. Did you take time to take a look at them?

Comment: Yes I did. I am already familiar with Doctrine and it's my main ORM. Among others, I like Outlet and RedBean.

Comment: This is a question I could use an answer to, but sadly it is not on-topic here.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [RedBean PHP](http://redbeanphp.com/) it is a lightweight ORM compatible with SQLite, PostgreSQL and MySQL.

Answer (score 6):

or you can try this simple and smart query builder [FluentPDO](https://github.com/lichtner/fluentpdo)

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking into this, and just found about [Propel ORM](http://propelorm.org/):

> **What is Propel exactly?**
>
> Propel is an open-source Object-Relational
>   Mapping (ORM) for SQL-Databases in PHP 5.4. It allows you to access
>   your database using a set of objects, providing a simple API for
>   storing and retrieving data.
>
> Additional to its ORM capabilities it does provide a query-builder,
>   database schema migration, reverse engineering of existing database
>   and much more.

Comment: Propel was great in its heyday, but they've struggled to find enough people to maintain it.